# Fling Gesture, Webview and Android

Tags: android, sdk, webview, gesture

I have a webview control that needs to support the fling gesture in Android in order to bring up a new record (load new data). This is occuring in a class that extends Activity. All the examples I've seen show how to implement gesture support for a textview, but nothing for webview. From what I've read Webview is another animal and it is "complicated".

I need to execute different actions for both left and right flings. Any code help would be appreciated as this totally has me stumped.

Here's my basic onCreate and my class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;

import android.webkit.WebView;

public class ArticleActivity extends Activity   {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



  Window  w = getWindow();

   w.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);

   WebView webview = new WebView(this);
  setContentView(webview); 



   w.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,
   R.drawable.gq);




  setDefaultKeyMode(DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL);
  populateFields();
webview.loadData(question + answer, "text/html", "utf-8");



//   
}
    private void populateFields() {

....


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the gesture by a different view other than a webview. Wrap the webview in a linearlayout, have the linearlayout catch the gesture, and then let the event pass to the webview.

Comment: how would I do that - wrap the webview in a linear layout and then have the linear layout catch the gesture? A beginner android guy here...thank you!